# Weather recommendations for Amsterdam

Tags: weather-and-climate, clothing, amsterdam

I am planning to travel Amsterdam about November and I would like to walk around the city and rent a bike for some tours.

I read to travel guide and the temperature is about 5ºC but they don't mention the kind of weather (rain, snow, humidity, ...)

I'll appreciate any advice about clothes and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because weather forecasts and historical weather data are off-topic (and available from other sources).

Comment: I think it is a valid question, weather makes a real difference in travel and the averages you will find online are not very useful if you do not know how to interpret them. Local knowledge will explain it much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say weather-wise November is probably the worst month to visit Amsterdam.

You can expect rain or drizzle almost at any and all times. Together with strong winds. Temperatures might not even be very low on paper (from 5ºC to 10ºC if you're lucky, but heck, right now it's 10ºC in the middle of August), but the chill factor from wind and rain makes it feel like you're on the North Pole. Since you're from Spain here is comparison: Wearing similar clothing I felt warmer in Madrid with -10ºC than in Amsterdam with +5ºC with rain and wind.

Biking in that weather is not enjoyable at all, especially if you have to struggle against strong headwind, splashing ice cold rain in your face. Locals that do bike usually use some form of sailing gear, with heavy duty rain jacket and impermeable pants and gloves. Gloves are particularity important, because otherwise your knuckles will freeze after just few minutes of biking.

If you're really, really lucky, you might actually have few sunny days. Other than that it's usually gloomy, 100% cloud coverage most of the time. Either way it gets very dark very early (especially comparing to Spain). Thus you have to remember to use lights on the bike. At that time of the year the police actually are on lookout for bikers who aren't using lights. The fines aren't huge (15-20 euros), but annoying.

On the other hand it's worth noting that by November there is significant drop in bike traffic and significant surge in number of people using trams.

Resuming, clothes you need are: windproof, waterproof, warm (what in Spain would be considered winter clothing).

Comment: I already have voted up every answer, but you even compared the weather with Spain. I'm from Canary Island, and we sometimes have the problem of rain + wind but minimum temperatures are about 14 ºC on winter.

Answer (score 4):

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam#Climate), in November, the average precipitation is 87.2mm. There are 13 days with ≥ 1 mm of precipitation, an average of 3 snow days, 61.7 mean monthly sunshine hours, and the humidity... 89%.

Comment: Very nice averages, but useless. Better know what to expect from the averages, if you have no knowledge, do not answer and leave it to people who do.

Answer (score 3):

It'll be cloudy, probably windy, with some rain every now and then. Sunset is around 16:30 to 17:00 depending on when in November, so it's dark early.

Rain usually doesn't last long, it shouldn't stop you from cycling around. But the wind is always there so a good coat is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Living there (well, near there) plan on plenty rain, cool but not usually cold temperatures (nights in November MAY drop below freezing, but not much, daytime peaks can be 10-15C), and mild winds.
So long trousers (or ditto skirts), and a light to medium (depending on how well you handle such temperatures) coat, plus an umbrella.

No need for winter gear, and if things turn out unusually cold you can always buy some locally.

Comment: Coming from the Canaries, better add two layers on the top and one on the bottom for all outside activities.